# Select value from another dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a two dataframes, one containing measure

| sensor_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 5 |
| AAA | 7 |
| BBB | 9 |
| BBB | 10 |

And another one containing corresponding levels:

| created_at | level_name | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | Level 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 2021-04-01 | Level 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 2021-04-01 | Level 3 | 7 | 15 |
| 2020-12-15 | Level 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 | Level 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2020-12-15 | Level 3 | 8 | 15 |

For each measurement, I would like to assign corresponding level_name from first dataframe based on value. As the levels can be changed, I only need to consider newest values.

I have tried:

```
df_values <- read.table(text = "sensor_id   value
AAA 5
AAA 7
BBB 9
BBB 10
",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_levels <- read.table(text ="   created_at    level_name  from    to
    1   2021-04-01  Level_1 0   5
    2   2021-04-01  Level_2 5   7
    3   2021-04-01  Level_3 7   15
    4   2020-12-15  Level_1 0   4
    5   2020-12-15  Level_2 4   8
    6   2020-12-15  Level_3 8   15
",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df_values$level_name<- df_levels %>% 
  filter(df_values[value] >= from ,df_values[value] < to ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(created_at)) %>% 
  head(1) %>% 
  select(level_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `fuzzyjoin` with `tidyverse`.

First, would limit your `df_levels` data.frame to the latest rows for each level. I was not sure how much data you have, but limiting at this step may be helpful, as you are only interested in the newest values.

Using `fuzzy_left_join`, you can join the two tables together based on value. Of note, you may want to modify with `>` and/or `<=` to handle edge cases.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

df_levels_new <- df_levels %>%
  mutate(created_at = as.Date(created_at, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(level_name) %>%
  arrange(created_at) %>%
  slice(1)

fuzzy_left_join(df_values,
                df_levels_new,
                by = c("value" = "from", "value" = "to"),
                match_fun = c(`>`, `<=`))
```

**Output**

```
  sensor_id value created_at level_name from to
1       AAA     5 2020-12-15    Level_2    4  8
2       AAA     7 2020-12-15    Level_2    4  8
3       BBB     9 2020-12-15    Level_3    8 15
4       BBB    10 2020-12-15    Level_3    8 15
```

Answer (score 0):

your question a bit unclear, thanks to your code I thought that you mean first level of "newest" date. Because they all are the same by date.

```
newest <- df_levels %>%
select(created_at,level_name) %>% 
filter(created_at==max(created_at)) %>%
head(1) %>% 
select(level_name) %>% 
pull


df_values %>% 
left_join(df_levels %>% select(level_name,to),by=c('value'='to')) %>% 
mutate(level_name=ifelse(is.na(level_name),newest,level_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the output you are looking for, but please let me know in what way I can improve it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)


df_levels %>%
  mutate(match = map2(from, to, ~ df_values$value[between(df_values$value, .x, .y - 1)])) %>%
  unnest_longer(match) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  left_join(df_values, by = c("match" = "value")) %>%
  mutate(created_at = as_date(created_at)) %>%
  arrange(desc(created_at)) %>%
  group_by(sensor_id, match) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1)


# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   sensor_id, match [4]
  created_at level_name  from    to match sensor_id
  <date>     <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <chr>    
1 2021-04-01 Level_2        5     7     5 AAA      
2 2021-04-01 Level_3        7    15     7 AAA      
3 2021-04-01 Level_3        7    15     9 BBB      
4 2021-04-01 Level_3        7    15    10 BBB
```